# Which Star Wars set is this?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

It is from the Star Wars theme but which one?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the silver jetpack, Jango Fett head, Phase I clone helmet, and orange battle droid parts, I believe it is 75015 Corporate Alliance Tank Droid.

[image: 75015 Corporate Alliance Tank Droid]